# How to enable Bluetooth on Atheros AR5B225?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, atheros

I changed wireless card in my Asus EB1505 to Atheros AR5B225 to use Bt. After some time trying to make it work I didn't made it. =(

I installed bunch of packages recommended for ath3k, installed a Bt-antenna to 'alt' pigtail of the card, set BIOS to be compatible with UEFI and other devices of such kind.

I lack of understanding of Bt-stack. =( What are other reasonable ways to enable Bt in my Ubuntu?

`lsusb` output is:
`cepreu@cepreu-EB1505:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c40a Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046a:0011 Cherry GmbH G83 (RS 6000) Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be a little late but to get reliable results from my bluetooth using that chipset I had to blacklist ath3k using `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf` then I edited rc.local `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and added `modprobe ath3k` above the last line that needs to be `exit 0` then save, exit and reboot

You do need firmware so `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

There is a timing issue with ath3k and the xhci drivers that usually stop ath3k from loading firmware but by delaying ath3k from loading this way gets the job done

`lsusb` output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c40a Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046a:0011 Cherry GmbH G83 (RS 6000) Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try as soon as it will be returned to me!

Comment: Got myself back this computer. Did as you instructed but no Bt-icon occurred.

Is there any test or a "bluetooth-indicator" package to install? Or if it doesn't appear it means that solution didn't helped?

Comment: Check `lsmod | grep bluetooth` to see if ath3k is loaded and then see if it will see any bt device that is discoverable with `hcitool scan`  if ath3k isn't loaded do `sudo modprobe ath3k` and if it is loaded and not working you will need to edit rc.local again and add `sleep 20` above the modprobe command, save and reboot.  There is a real fix on the way but I don't know how long before it is available in the Ubuntu kernel

Comment: looks like `ath3k' is loaded, but device isn't discoverable. What's in that case? =(

`cepreu@cepreu-EB1505:~$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             446190  11 bnep,ath3k,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
cepreu@cepreu-EB1505:~$ hcitool scan 
Device is not available: No such device'

Comment: `dmesg | grep firmware` as it sounds like a firmware issue

Comment: sorry didn't notice your comment.

`dmesg | grep firmware` gives absolutely nothing.

Comment: What does `rfkill list all` show

Comment: Might as well post `lsusb` in case it is a weird one and `uname -r`

Comment: rfkill list all:cepreu@cepreu-EB1505:~$ rfkill list all                                                    
0: phy0: Wireless LAN                                                                      
        Soft blocked: no                                                                   
        Hard blocked: no                                                                   
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN                                                                 
        Soft blocked: no                                                                   
        Hard blocked: no

Comment: sorry my Android doesn't let me to format a comment. Will post from the PC.

Comment: rfkill results are good, now just need to see `lsusb` and `uname -r`  On my android phone I have to use the Sym key and then the 1/2 to get the tick mark for code

Comment: Can't see anything about Bt in `lsusb` output. 

`cepreu@cepreu-EB1505:~$ uname -r
3.16.0-31-generic`

P.s.Looks like I have no such keys atAndroid. =(

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced `lsusb` output to your answer and I can't revert it.

Comment: For some reason your bluetooth device is not discovered by Linux with your current kernel and PC.  I do not know if a newer kernel will fix it.  I own a Toshiba that acts the same and I have tried 3 different wifi/bt cards in it and the only way I have bluetooth is using one of my bluetooth dongles.  The bluetooth in those cards work in another laptop.  Are there any BIOS updates for your laptop?  It is the only thing that might help that I can think of

Comment: I will try to update BIOS and kernel.

Comment: Thank you! Tried everything proposed, but nothing helps. Will wait for support in a recent kernel.